# Fortran/MPI non-blocking send of non-persistent data

Tags: c, fortran, mpi

Consider the following:

```
subroutine send_to_friend(a,b,c,request)
  implicit none
  include 'mpif.h'  !use mpi if you've built the mpif90 bindings...

  real a,b,c
  real buff(3)
  integer tag,dest,ierr,request

  tag = 50
  dest = 0

  buff(1) = a
  buff(2) = b
  buff(3) = c
  call MPI_Isend(buff,3,MPI_REAL,dest,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,request,ierr)
return
end subroutine send_to_friend
```

This will likely not work because `buff` will be put on the stack (with most modern compilers anyway), but that will be wiped clean whenever the subroutine exits.  Allocating the array also doesn't help because according to [here](http://www.nsc.liu.se/~boein/f77to90/a3.html) (section 10), allocated arrays are automatically deallocated when you exit the procedure -- in C, this would be a memory leak (also bad).  What's the proper way to do something like this?  Should I declare the array with the `save` attribute?  (`static` in C).  Is this design inherently flawed to begin with?

Comment: Yeah, I'd be tempted to say that the design has problems inherently; even with `save` what happens if you call this subroutine twice in quick succession?   You could use [`MPI_Bsend`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Bsend.html) with "enough" user defined buffer space and make managing the buffer MPI's problem, but [Buffered Sends Are Evil](http://blogs.cisco.com/performance/top-10-reasons-why-buffered-sends-are-evil/)

Comment: @JonathanDursi -- That's why you return the `request` -- To make sure that the data has been sent before you call this again.  how else are you supposed to do something like this?  The current process has lots of things to do while sending the data to `0`...and I don't want to wait if `0` is too busy to receive the message right away... Isn't that the whole purpose of an `isend` to begin with?

Comment: If you have to manually handle checking previous requests to know if it's safe to call this subroutine, then I just don't see the point of this subroutine.  You're not really abstracting anything away if you have to do a bunch of low level stuff to be able to safely call this subroutine.  Maybe you've already got that covered at a higher level in your code but it's hard to tell from just seeing this routine.  If you really want to do this, I'd just suggest using bsend (note: not ibsend, for the same reason) or pass it a buffer and have it safely handle the buffering.

Comment: Let me try rewriting that comment more coherently; right now, even with `save`, the safe handling of the temporary buffer is *both* the responsibility of the higher level code (check request before calling) and the lower level code (stuff the buffer full of data).  That's awkward and error-prone.   My suggestion would be have all the buffer-handling done in the calling code (allocate a buffer, stuff it, and pass it to the routine) or all in the lower level code (using Bsend or your own buffer-handling code), just not both.

Comment: @JonathanDursi -- My use case is actually more complex than this.  The data to be sent (recieved) is in common blocks which means that I need to include those common blocks in the calling procedures -- but that could introduce namespace clashes, etc, etc. (Note, I don't have control over those design decisions).  I'd also like to be able to do this from at least 2 places in the code so encapsulating it seems like a good idea.  Finally, the `request` could all be handled locally (with `save`).  The first time you enter the function you don't `MPI_Wait`, every other time you do.

Comment: I would have proposed the same - save the request locally, initialised to `MPI_REQUEST_NULL` and always wait on it. Waits on null requests are allowed in the standard and result in no-ops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SAVE` should be fine (best combine with allocatable), provided you do not come to other problems, which would require Fortran to pass the array via copy-in copy-out, it has to be done by reference (do not try to send non-contiguous data using nonblocking MPI).

If you have `save` variables in the routine, also do not try to run it from more threads, if you combine MPI/OpenMP.

Comment: Isn't is safe to use heap variables as read-only in OpenMP, or was that a misunderstanding on my part?  (anyway, I'm not using OpenMP, so this is merely academic curiosity).  Also, why do you say that it's best to combine with allocatable?  (I thought about that, but then I need to check if it has been allocated which seems a bit messy)

Comment: Because automatic arrays are out of question, compile time constant are good for small things and pointers can damage performance (not in simple cases).

Comment: Ad OpenMP: I just wanted to point out static arrays may cause the procedures to be non-thread safe. Of course there are specific ways how to overcome that in every threading model.